# LibGDX - Universal Tween engine isn't working properly

Tags: libgdx, tween

I just added the tween engine to my project. I added the two .jar files to the libs folder and it shows up in my project. I also added

```
compile fileTree(dir: "../libs", include: "*.jar")
```

to the core part to the build.gradle

But when I try to implement it in my project It doesn't work. Here's what I have:

```
package com.badlogic.gdx.tween;

public class SpriteAccessor implements TweenAccessor {

}
```

Currently theirs a red squigily line under "TweenAccessor". I think I'm supposted to import something but theirs no option to do that. I probably installed it wrong but I have no idea what the problem is. Anyone know?

The error that I get is "TweenAccessor cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + O helps?

Comment: refreshed Gradle dependencies?

Comment: Did that as well. I will will try it again just incase something didn't work.